# Access coordinates array from JSON object with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to get the coordinates from a JSON file.

**JSON File Structure:**

```
    {
  "parkeerlocaties": [
    {
      "parkeerlocatie": {
        "Locatie": "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.9032801,52.3824545]}"
      }
    }
```

I can access the `Locatie` object and it returns the following:

```
{"type":"Point","coordinates":[4.9032801,52.3824545]}
```

But when I am trying to get the coordinates from the JSON file, I get undefined back.

**Code:**

```
$.getJSON(parkingUrl, function(parkingData) {
                pData = parkingData.parkeerlocaties;
                for (var x = 0; x < pData.length; x++ ) {
                  ploc = parkingData["parkeerlocaties"][x]["parkeerlocatie"]["Locatie"]["coordinates"];
                  console.log(ploc);
                };
            });
      };
```

So, how can I get the coordinates from the JSON file?

Answer (score 3):

Your `Locatie` key points to a string, not an object. You can use `JSON.parse()` to convert this string into an object so that you can then access the `coordinates` key.

```
ploc = JSON.parse(parkingData["parkeerlocaties"][x]["parkeerlocatie"]["Locatie"])["coordinates"];
```

So you code should look like:

```
$.getJSON(parkingUrl, function(parkingData) {
  pData = parkingData.parkeerlocaties;
  for (var x = 0; x < pData.length; x++) {
    ploc = JSON.parse(parkingData["parkeerlocaties"][x]["parkeerlocatie"]["Locatie"])["coordinates"];
    console.log(ploc);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! I tried the JSON.parse before, but I placed the parentheses wrong after coordinates, instead of infront of it.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `JSON.parse` to convert the JSON string to JSON object.

```
JSON.parse(parkingData.parkeerlocaties[0].parkeerlocatie.Locatie).coordinates
```

Here Locatie is a JSON string.

```
$.getJSON(parkingUrl, function(parkingData) {
            pData = parkingData.parkeerlocaties;
            for (var x = 0; x < pData.length; x++ ) {
              ploc  = JSON.parse(parkingData.parkeerlocaties[x].parkeerlocatie.Locatie).coordinates

              console.log(ploc);
            };
        });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to save the file avoiding escape sequence "\"

```
{ "parkeerlocaties": [ { "parkeerlocatie": { "Locatie": {"type":"Point","coordinates":[4.9032801,52.3824545]} } }
```

Comment: Please do not answer with a comment/question. Understandably, your rep is too low to comment, but that still does not mean answers should be used to make comments as an alternative. It would be preferable if you deleted this.

Answer (score 0):

I have added following code for your further reference. It will help you to understand your mistake. Your json String missing "}" and "]" at the end of json string. Better to used JSON formatted for validate your JSON. [json validation](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

```
    try{
        var test = "{\"parkeerlocaties\": [{  \"parkeerlocatie\": {\"Locatie\": {\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[4.9032801,52.3824545]}}}]}";
        var jsondata = JSON.parse(test);
        var pData = jsondata.parkeerlocaties;

        for (var x = 0; x < pData.length; x++ ) {
          var ploc = jsondata["parkeerlocaties"][x]["parkeerlocatie"]["Locatie"]["coordinates"];
          alert(ploc);
        };
   }catch(e){alert(e)}
```